# Write Nested Select Query in Laravel 5.3

Tags: sql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-query-builder

How do I write a complex query in Laravel 5.3? I am trying but not getting the result I expect.

**Query**

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT posts.post_id 
FROM posts 
WHERE ((posts.user_id = 1 AND posts.user_type = 'user') 
    OR (posts.user_id IN (1) AND posts.user_type = 'page'))) posts 
    WHERE posts.post_id > '0' ORDER BY posts.post_id DESC
```

Please help me write this using Laravel Query Builder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your answer .

```
$MyQuery = DB::table(DB::Raw("(SELECT
                               posts.post_id
                               FROM
                               posts
                               WHERE
                               (
                                 (
                                   posts.user_id = 1
                                   AND posts.user_type = 'user'
                                  )
                                  OR 
                                  (
                                    posts.user_id IN (1)
                                    AND posts.user_type = 'page'
                                   )
                                )
                                )"))
            ->where('posts.post_id','>',"0")->orderBy("posts.post_id" , "DESC")->get();
```

Try printing query once using `->toSql()` like this

```
echo $MyQuery = DB::table(DB::Raw("(SELECT
                                    posts.post_id
                                    FROM
                                    posts
                                    WHERE((
                                           posts.user_id = 1
                                           AND posts.user_type = 'user'
                                           )
                                           OR(
                                           posts.user_id IN (1)
                                           AND posts.user_type = 'page'
                                           )))"))
            ->where('posts.post_id','>',"0")->orderBy("posts.post_id" , "DESC")->toSql();

            die();
```

Comment: Nice Answer for this thank's But I am Use Model To Build SELECT Query

Comment: @NarendraJhala [this](http://laravel.io/forum/03-05-2014-nested-query-in-from)  can help you more to understand ,

Answer (score 1):

@Punit Gajjar has provided one solution, but that's not quite what your question was given the terms **Query Builder**. His solution will work, but half it it doesn't make use of the query builder (it's just a copy/paste and throwing your SQL into a raw query, which is essentially exactly the same thing as you had before) and therefore I feel it's necessary to provide you with an additional option:

```
Post::where('post_id', '>', 0)
    ->where(function($query) {

       $query->where(function($subquery) {
           $subquery->where('user_id', 1)->where('user_type', 'user');
       })->orWhere(function($subquery) {
           $subquery->whereIn('user_id', [1])->where('user_type', 'page');
       });

    })
    ->orderBy('post_id', 'DESC')
    ->get();
```

I've kept variables names short just for readability purposes, but the argument in the anonymous functions (`$query` and `$subquery`) are the query builder instances.